# redirecting output of 'find' command to 'vim'

Tags: vim, redirect, find

I am doing a find $PWD -name 'filename' | vim -

expecting the file filename to be opened in vim editor. but it is not working.
In this case, I am sure that there exists just one file with name 'filename'.

Also the result of find gives the complete path on stdout.

Comment: using `command | vim -` tells vim to read the output from `command` and put it into a buffer. (As opposed to opening those files.)

Comment: @pydave I missed the '-' in your comment. Important!

Comment: @pydave Incidentally, `vim <(command)` does the same, using Bash process substitution, and this works with more than just vim. e.g. to see the differences between two directories, use `diff <(ls -l dir1) <(ls -l dir2)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
vim "$(find "$PWD" -name 'filename')"
```

or

```
find "$PWD" -name 'filename' -exec vim {} \;
```

(You can drop `"$PWD"`, by the way. `find` starts the search from current directory by default.)

Comment: This does not work for me. `vim "$(find "$PWD" -name 'filename')"` opens a new file whos name is a concatenation of all the filenames output from find. This is on OSX.

Comment: Ah. The OP specifies there is just one matching file. My objection is therefore lessened.

Comment: You probably want to use `+` to concatenate the results instead of `;` to operate on single results when ending the find: `find "$PWD" -name 'filename' -exec vim {} +` should open the files in one vim instance (so they're accessibly from `:args`).

Comment: "You can drop "$PWD", by the way" -- note that adding $PWD can make a difference if you need the full path (instead of relative). (Like if you're writing the results to a file.)

Comment: @JonathanHartley: That doesn't work because you're quoting the output. If you don't quote the output (and don't have spaces in your filenames) does it work? Regardless, you're better off using `-exec` (with `+`).

Comment: @pydave Aha! Yes, `vim $(find . -name FILENAME)` (without the double-quotes shown in the answer) does work, and if multiple files match, then they are opened in different buffers. Thanks!

Comment: @pydave And: Yes, `find . -name test_models.py -exec vim {} \;` does work, and if multiple filenames match, and in contrast to my last comment, they are opened consecutively in separate instances of vim (so I have to quit the first in order to see the second). As you say, changing the '\;' to '\+' opens these in the same vim. Thanks again!

Comment: @JonathanHartley: In your last example (with +), you could also use `vim -o` to open them in splits (see also `-O` and `-p`). Also, you don't need to escape + because it doesn't mean anything special to bash.

Answer (score 9):

`find . -name 'filename' -print0 | xargs -0 vim`

should also work. You might want to read up on xargs, which is a handy thing to know about.

Comment: This does not work for me. `find . -name 'utility' -print0 | xargs -0 vim` instead opens a single new file, whose name is a concatenation of the output from find. This is on OSX.

Comment: Ah. The OP specifies there is just one matching file. My objection is therefore lessened

Answer (score 4):

Mentioned in @idbrii's comment, but my favorite is:

```
find . -name 'filename' -type f -exec vim {} \+
```

This opens up each file found in its own buffer ready to be navigated with `:next` and `:prev`. Tested on OSX, but I'm fairly certain it will work on Linux too.

Answer (score 3):

One way I find is very easy is enclosing the find command with backticks (character under tilde on most keyboards) and passing it to vim.

```
vim `find . -name myfile`
```

In fact, you can use backtick for any command to get the literal string output of the command.

Comment: How does this answer not have more votes?!? Genious!